# How to use ComponentDidMount to render values to form in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I have a form for which values should be fetched from an api. I'm using axios to get the values. How do I display the fetched values to the form fields? Where can I set the props value to state. I'm using redux for global state managemnt.

```
class ABC extends Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
       name:"",
       email:"" //can i set the value of props here?
    }
ComponentDidMount{
     this.props.actionGetABC();  //Call to action to fetch details from API
}
       render(){
         return(
             <div>
               <Form>
                <Form.Input
                inline 
                required
                label="Email"
                type="email"
                value={this.state.email} //How change i render the value 
                                          fetched from api here?
                onChange={this.handleChangeEmail}
                />
                <Form.Input
                inline
                required
                label="Name"
                type="text"
                icon="user"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.handleChangeName}
                />
              </Form>
             </div>
            );
         }
}
```

Comment: Is your action storing data in redux ? If so then `connect` component with store and access value. If not then instead of making api call from action do right there or use service and store result in state and manipulate

Comment: Yes, I',m using connect and action is storing the data. How to get this value in the form?

Comment: you can take that store state value to local state. can do this in `componentWillReceiveProps` and by doing setState (store value to local state). there are many other ways depend on your use case

Answer (score 0):

You can do that directly in componentDidMount method like

```
ComponentDidMount{
     this.props.actionGetABC().then( data => {
        this.setState({
           name: data.name,
           email: data.email
         });
     }); //Call to action to fetch details from API
}
```

for above solution to work you need to return success action in actionGetABC action call

Comment: is it possible to directly access action payload in this way? I think question is not clear enough. how is action or redux (as he mentioned tags in question)

Comment: I think you misspelled `setState()` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider `form` is your store state with profileForm object which store profile form values with field `name` and `email` (value receive from API)

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>({
    form: state.profileForm
});
const mapDispatchToProps=()=>({
   ....//your action call  actionGetABC() code your aware of it
})
```

connect it with your Form Component `connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(FormComponent)`

Now in FormComponent's `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` deprecated

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   if(nextProps.name && nextProps.email) //checking data available in profileForm (name and email received from API)
   this.setState({name:nextProps.name, email:nextProps.email})
}
```

Form is same as that of you. You can directly access store value in form but you need to call action for every onChange event of textInput so stored in localstate.

I tried my best to explain case,if any suggestion or questions, please do comment

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). Is there any other way than using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps ?Since it is deprecated, I don't want to use it.

Comment: you can use `static getDerivedStateFromProps()` or  `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)`  this instead